# How do I redirect an output of a command e.g. 'echo Hi' to an output of another command that returns a path e.g. 'tty' (that returns, /dev/pts/1)?

Tags: command-line, bash

How do I redirect an output of a command e.g. `echo Hi` to an output of another command that returns a path e.g. `tty` (that returns, `/dev/pts/1`) without having to copy-paste the output to a command like this:

```
echo Hi > /dev/pts/1 |
```

Comment: and I'm a new user of a bash shell :)

Comment: You can edit your own question by clicking on the [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1131862/edit) button just below your post.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The keyword is *command substitution*. You essentially want a redirection like

```
$ echo Hi > PROGRAM
```

But where PROGRAM is replaced (substituted) by its own output. This is what the `$()` syntax does, in your case

```
$ echo Hi > $(tty)
```

First executes `tty`, then captures the output (`/dev/pts/1` in this case), and replaces `$(tty)` with it before executing the rest of the line, i.e. redirecting the echo there.

You can find more information, including some technical details that may become relevant in other contexts, [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html) and in the [Linux documentation project](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html). The former covers the gist, the latter is richer in details and has examples, but IMHO a bit harder to read. Note that the Linux documentation project uses the old-fashioned backtick syntax. You should stick with `$(PROGRAM)`, since it’s easier to nest.